# Checking integer lists under a column for each record to tag/classify each record (SQL) - reverse index match (or some other way)?

Tags: sql, postgresql, redash

I have a problem I'm trying to resolve. I'd love to get your ideas or help with the method I have in my mind. I created a good analogy for it: I need to tag each record in a table if they're partial purchases or not. It is clearer if you can look at the example below:

I have products classified as Level 2 and Level 1. And each Level 1 product is associated with one or more level 2 products. I only need to check Level 1 purchases, because Level 2 ones can't be partial purchase.

Partial purchase: If a customer who purchased Level 1 product didn't purchase any of the associated Level 2 products, that purchase is partial.

It should be simple, but the columns I have hold the necessary information in a weird way.

Method I have in mind:

For each level 1 purchase

1. Get all the Level 2 purchases from that customer with a cte
2. Check the product dependency columns of those:
   if this level 1 product's product ID is in any of those lists(!) it's not a partial purchase. If not it's partial.

This should work, but I can't get it to work in SQL.
My question:

- How can I check the each element in each list in the entire column for all the Level 2 purchases from that customer? Because I don't have any way of associating these level 1 & level 2 purchases based on their product dependencies.

[example image showing the columns etc. - first three records here should explain enough about the problem & the expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K3jSe.png)

Any help is appreciated, I'm a bit slow on SQL
What we have is PostgreSQL through Redash

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using `unnest()` function of postgresql. This function are converted array list to row for easily using.
I don't know type of your `product_dependency` field. If this field is not a `int array` so you can convert this field to array using `string_to_array()` function and after then use `unnest()`.
I wrote an example for you:

```
select * from your_table t1 
where 
    t1.product_level = 'Level 1' and 
    t1.product_id not in (select unnest(product_dep) from your_table where customer_id = t1.customer_id)
```

And result (gets only partial purchases):

```
id  customer_id product_id  product_level
3   B           1           Level 1
6   D           5           Level 1
```

Comment: Lovely! This can get it to work! Can we use this as "in" instead of "not in" as well?
I'm considering the memory here, can we use that to look for only the purchases for that product?

I want to use it while creating my_table and use a variation of the code you provided there as well 





<code>
select * from your_table t1 
where 
    t1.product_id in (select unnest(product_dep) from your_table)
    OR
    t1.product_id = {{user_input}}` <code>


When I do this, because it checks for the entire column now, it acceps all the records, not only the ones that have it.

Answer (score 0):

I will write an alternative query for you:
Example:

```
select 
    t1.id, t1.customer_id, t1.product_id, t1.product_level,  
    case when product_level = 'Level 1' then (t1.product_id not in (select unnest(product_dep) from your_table where customer_id = t1.customer_id)) else false end as partial_purchase
from your_table t1

Result: 
id  customer_id product_id  product_level   partial_purchase
1   A           1           Level 1         false
2   A           2           Level 2         false
3   B           1           Level 1         true
4   C           3           Level 2         false
5   C           4           Level 1         false
6   D           5           Level 1         true
7   D           6           Level 2         false
```

You can use this query in your subquery for easily filtering like as:

```
where partial_purchase = true 
or 
where partial_purchase = false  
or 
where product_id = <id>
```